# NUnit tests sharding

Tags: nunit

In our code we have ~7000 unit and integration tests and ~3000 functional tests. All tests take about 3 hours to run, so we are trying to run our tests in parallel. Unfortunately, tests share the same DB so they should be launched one-by-one. Our current solution is to separate tests into several NUnit categories by hand and run particular categories on different boxes using Jenkins.

This is nice solution, but it has some drawbacks:

- all tests should be marked with particular categories, so if there are any tests without category or in wrong category, they will never be launched on Jenkins.
- all categories should be rebalanced from time to time to keep the running time of different categories the same.

Is there any other ways to "shard" NUnit tests across machines? May be there are some tools that helps to create a set of nunit projects from solution?

Comment: If your tests share the same DB and should be launched one-by-one, how is sharding going to help exactly?

Comment: We can run tests on different virtual boxes that has its own DB, so if there is a way to split all unit tests to several nunit projects, the could be sharded to different boxes.